# Override Eclipse plugin default preferences

Tags: eclipse, preferences, rcp

I am developing an Eclipse RCP application and use a plugin provided by a third party. I need to change the default values of some of this plugin's preferences. Can I do that from my own code, without the need to change the plugin's internal `PreferenceInitializer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set preferences for other plugins through a file registered with the preferenceCustomization extension in your product extension.

The file is usually named plugin_customization.ini.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePreferences/article.html#preferences_plugin.ini